# Excel VBA Findnext and Split Methods

Tags: excel, vba, split, find, delimiter

I need help figuring out how to solve this problem using VBA. I have a messy CSV file that needs to be organized into a table. It currently looks like this:
Edit: looks like I can't post images until I have 10 reps. Let's just say it's disorganized.

I created another worksheet that contains the headers called "Account Number", "Account Name", "As of Date", "CUSIP #", "Market Value", "Maturity Date", "Description", "Tax Cost", and "Unit". I need to copy those values into the appropriate columns.

A Find function is probably the best way I can think of to find the cells with the value "Account Number:". However, "Account Number: 1234567890" is one cell. I'll need to split the strings up and extract just the "1234567890" part. The extracted part is then pasted into the table (the new worksheet that is) in the appropriate header. When it "FindNext", it must paste the new value into an empty cell below it (in the new worksheet). This process is repeated until the end. I don't know how best to approach this. Ditto for the other headers.

Answer (score 0):

[Range].TextToColumns is a handy VBA method for converting comma-delimited text directly into a table.  For example,

```
 Range("A1:A30").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited,         TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _ 
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False,   Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False,              Comma:=True, _
    Space:=False,                  other:=False
```

Will parse a comma-delimited data dump in cells A1 to A30 and will convert it into a table starting at C1.  The table will have 30 rows and as many columns as necessary to show your data in a table format.

For example, if cells A1:A5 contains the following:

```
13.67,4182085,13.80,13.54,"4/8/2015",65.10,15.50,"Alcoa Inc. Common Stock"
78.69,6385991,79.36,78.30,"4/8/2015",14.15,86.31,"American Express Company Common"
153.36,2760993,153.50,152.19,"4/8/2015",20.78,135.98,"Boeing Company (The) Common Sto"
15.61,7138359,15.74,15.50,"4/8/2015",43.36,16.59,"Bank of America Corporation Com"
80.44,4191357,81.24,79.92,"4/8/2015",13.68,90.60,"Caterpillar, Inc. Common Stock"
```

then that statement above will create a 5x8 table in cells C1:J5 as follows:

```
13.67   4182085  13.80  13.54   42102   65.10    15.50  Alcoa Inc. Common Stock
78.69   6385991  79.36  78.30   42102   14.15    86.31  American Express Company Common
153.36  2760993 153.50  152.19  42102   20.78   135.98  Boeing Company (The) Common Sto
15.61   7138359  15.74  15.50   42102   43.36    16.59  Bank of America Corporation Com
80.44   4191357  81.24  79.92   42102   13.68    90.60  Caterpillar, Inc. Common Stock
```

Full documentation is available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff193593.aspx

Cheat sheet is:

*expression*`.TextToColumns(Destination, DataType, TextQualifier, ConsecutiveDelimiter, Tab, Semicolon, Comma, Space, Other, OtherChar, FieldInfo, DecimalSeparator, ThousandsSeparator, TrailingMinusNumbers)`

Where *expression* is a Range object.

All parameters are optional.  Parameters are:

`Destination` ... A Range object that specifies where Microsoft Excel will place the results. If the range is larger than a single cell, the top left cell is used.

`DataType` ... xlDelimited or 1 (Default) indicates that the file is delimited by delimiter characters.   xlFixedWidth or 2 indicates that the data in the file is arranged in columns of fixed widths.

`TextQualifier` ... use TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote or TextQualifier:=2 to specify that text is surrounded by double quotes, xlTextQualifierSingleQuote or 1 for single quotes, and xlTextQualifierNone or -4142 (huh??) for no quotes.

`ConsecutiveDelimiter` ... True to have Microsoft Excel consider consecutive delimiters as one delimiter. The default value is False.

`Tab` ... True to have DataType be xlDelimited and to have the tab character be a delimiter. The default value is False.

`Semicolon` ... True to have DataType be xlDelimited and to have the semicolon be a delimiter. The default value is False.

`Comma` ... True to have DataType be xlDelimited and to have the comma be a delimiter. The default value is False.

`Space` ... True to have DataType be xlDelimited and to have the space character be a delimiter. The default value is False.

`Other` ... True to have DataType be xlDelimited and to have the character specified by the OtherChar argument be a delimiter. The default value is False.

`OtherChar` ... The delimiter character when Other is True.

`FieldInfo` ... An array containing parse information for the individual columns of data. This one is very powerful for tables that have funky formatting.  I think you can use it in your case to specify field names.  See Microsoft documentation.

`DecimalSeparator`, `ThousandsSeparator`, `TrailingMinusNumbers` are self explanatory

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, based on your example, you could use a simple spreadsheet function. If Cell A1 looks like

```
Account Number:X7D4332, Account Name:Fidelity, As of Date: 3/15/15, CUSIP #:3136AMKZ1
```

then

```
B1 =FIND("Account Number:", A1)
C1 =LEN("Account Number:")
D1 =FIND(",",A1,C1)
E1 =MID(A1, B1+C1, D1 - C1 - B1)
```

will show "X7D4332" in cell E1.  If you substitute "Account Name:" for "Account Number:" then you will get "Fidelity."  Etc.

No macros, no complicated VBA Range Methods.